# Insert data on a "point" column with mybatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ibatis

I'm using mybatis in my project and I need to insert data on a column of type "point" (mysql).

How can I do it?

I've managed to create a mapper for my table but how can I specify the geometry data type for the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql statement for Point column is

```
INSERT INTO t1 (pt_col) VALUES(Point(1,2))
```

Thus you can just pass in the values accordingly in Mybatis?

A basic example will be like

```
@Insert( "INSERT INTO t1( pt_col ) values( Point( #{x}, #{y} )" )
public int insert( @Param("x") int x, @Param("y") int y );
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is probably right though I don't have time to test it now. I worked around the solution converting all columns to base type and creating a view with non-standard types that is not accessed through mybatis. I'll come back to this (better) approach if I have more time for this task.